# Is there any way to get a WordPress category name from the post title?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I imported a blog to WordPress and it has over 300 posts. I noticed it didn't put the categories to the WordPress posts, but it did import all the category names. Luckily, the category name is in the post name (for ex. 'Science - Earth Is Round' would be the post title and 'Science' would be the category). Since the categories all exist, is there any way I could run a script that would look in the post title to see if any category matches text that it is in the title, and if so set that as the category?

Comment: That's definitely possible. Can't write the code off the top of my head though. You could may also be able to write a MySQL insert query to do this too. Would be a little tricky, but possible also. For the mysql query you'd want to do a "insert into select"

Comment: Ahh that would work perfectly. I didn't even think about using a mysql query. Working on that now :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Here is a modified select query that matches terms to posts based on if the term is in the title:

```
select p.id, tt.term_taxonomy_id, t.term_id,  t.name, p.post_title
from wp_terms t 
join wp_posts p on INSTR(p.post_title, t.name)
join wp_term_taxonomy tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id 
where p.post_type = 'post'
```

Here is the insert query you'd use (note that this query will throw an error if you insert duplicate object_id and term_taxonomy_id pairs due to primary key constraint):

```
insert into wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
    select p.id, tt.term_taxonomy_id, 0
    from wp_terms t 
    join wp_posts p on INSTR(p.post_title, t.name)
    join wp_term_taxonomy tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id 
    where p.post_type = 'post'
```

If you do get the primary key constraint error, you can use `insert ignore`

```
insert ignore into wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
    select p.id, tt.term_taxonomy_id, 0
    from wp_terms t 
    join wp_posts p on INSTR(p.post_title, t.name)
    join wp_term_taxonomy tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id 
    where p.post_type = 'post'
```

**EDIT 1:**

Here's a query that may work for you:

```
insert into wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
    select p.id, tt.term_taxonomy_id, 0 
    from wp_posts p 
    join wp_terms t on t.name = substring_index(p.post_title, ' ',  1)
    join wp_term_taxonomy tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id 
    where p.post_type = 'post'
```

Here I'm assuming that the titles are like your example. You may need to adjust the delimiter.

Additionally, I'd run the select query by itself to test what data you are getting back and to make sure you're not getting duplicates and stuff. And yeah definitely backup your database first.

```
select p.id, tt.term_taxonomy_id, 0 
from wp_posts p 
join wp_terms t on t.name = substring_index(p.post_title, ' ',  1)
join wp_term_taxonomy tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id 
where p.post_type = 'post'
```

Also here is a better select query for debugging results:

```
select p.id, tt.term_taxonomy_id, t.term_id, substring_index(p.post_title, ' ',  1) 
from wp_posts p 
join wp_terms t on t.name = substring_index(p.post_title, ' ',  1)
join wp_term_taxonomy tt on tt.term_id = t.term_id 
where p.post_type = 'post'
```

Comment: If my title is like "Eat Chinese Food For Dinner" and a category "Chinese Food" exists, would that mysql query set that as the category? Or would it look for a category by the name of 'eat'?

Comment: Yes, the way I set it up, it would be Eat. Can you provide some examples of where the categories could be located? Maybe I can provide a query

Comment: How many categories do you have. It may be possible to some more hardcoded if you don't have hundreds of categories.

Comment: Yes, basically each title would be "Watch {Quick And Easy} tutorials for Your Store" and words in brackets would be the category, no matter how many words there are if that makes sense. Each post begins with the word watch. And I have about 50 categories.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have another query idea. Give me a few minutes to write it up. But basically you can do a "Phrase match" on the title based on your categories.

Comment: Right that's what I was thinking along the lines of. I just don't know MySQL very well.

Comment: The select query displays what I would want to set the category should be, but the insert query displays the error "#1062 - Duplicate entry '857-2' for key 'PRIMARY'" and then I click browse and it says "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE CONCAT_WS("-", object_id,  term_taxonomy_id,  term_order)
               ' at line 3 "

Comment: I'm going to take this to chat. So this comment thread doesn't get too long. Is that ok?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46727/discussion-between-gohn67-and-user2087587)